# Qt Circular Depencency between classes and its members

Tags: c++, qt, circular-dependency

This is C++. I have a main class:

```
#include <QObject>

#include "Logger.h"
#include "PluginManager.h"

class Main : QObject
{
  Main();
  ~Main();
  Logger &getLogger();

signals:
  // Some signals

public slots:
  // Some slots
};
```

And now I have the PluginManager class.

The constructor is:

```
PluginManager( QObject *parent = 0 );
```

And I construct it in the main class like this:

```
pluginManager = new PluginManager(this);
```

Now, the problem: The server class needs to create the PluginManager (obviously) and the PluginManager has to get the logger from the server class *and* all the plugins too!

```
parent()->getLogger(); // This doesn't work (PluginManager)
```

Error: 'class QObject' has no member named 'getLogger'

Have I to create a class and derivate it from all the classes?
Please, put any example that can be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To face compile-time dependencies there are two methods:

1. Forward declare the classes you need.
2. Use an interface to break the cyclic dependency.

### Forward declarations

In your `PluginManager.h` file you just write

```
class Main;
```

at the top of you file in order to forward declare `Main`. Then you declare the constructor of the `PluginManager` as

```
PluginManager( Main * parent );
```

In the implementation file of the `PluginManager` you need to include the header which defines the `Main` class then.

### Interfaces

The second option uses an interface avoids the cyclic dependency alltogether. It works like this:

```
class MainInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainInterface( QObject * parent ) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~MainInterface() {}
    virtual void someFunc1() = 0;
    virtual void someFunc2() = 0;
    // ...
};

class PluginManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PluginManager( MainInterface * parent = 0 ) 
        : QObject(parent) { /* ... */ }
    // ... other functions ...
};

class Main : public MainInterface
{
public:
    Main( QObject * parent = 0 )
        : MainInterface(parent) {}
    virtual void someFunc1();
    virtual void someFunc2();
    // ...
};
```

The dependency graph now looks like this

```
MainInterface                          PluginManager
  A       A              instead of        A  |
  |       |                                |  V
Main   PluginManager                       Main
```

### Your choice

What alternative you want to use is your choice. If the two classes work together as an indivisible part of your program then use the easier approach of forward declaring. If you want to have these components decoupled and avoid dependencies as much as possible, then use the second approach.

Comment: Forward declarations doesn't work, I've already tried it :S I'll try the interface. Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with the forward declarations? Did you change the PluginManager to take a `Main *` instead of a `QObject *`?

Comment: PluginManager is declared at the Main class as "PluginManager *pluginManager;" and the constructor creates it.

Answer (score 0):

As far the error "'class QObject' has no member named 'getLogger'" is concerned, it has nothing to do with circular dependency.

```
PluginManager( QObject *parent = 0 )
```

The type of parent is QObject *, which has no member getLogger(), which is a member of Main class.

Comment: You don't understand my question. The title is circular dependency because i didn't have the idea of an Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Does the logger part keeps changing in the application ?

If not then while creating the PluginManager you should initialize logger also by passing an addition param, removing the later dependency of plugin manager over the server

Comment: Changing the application? The logger only log info to the console and forks into a file. I don't understand your answer. There will be more classes inside main that need acces to the main class.

Comment: Creation of Classes inside Main is the responsibility of your Main class. If those classes need some additional information from Main that should be provided at creation time rather than fetching them later which will help you removing the dependency that should not exist